# wc and grep together for all files in a folder

Tags: grep, xargs, wc

Hi I want to count particular lines using grep for all files in a folder

I know doing

```
find . -name 'FileName' | xargs wc -l
```

Helps with counting lines for all files. But I wonder how can I include grep in it.

Ideally I want to do `grep @ FileName | wc -l` for all the files in the folder. 
Thanks,
Mitra

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Get a count of matching lines in all the `.php` files in the current directory? In the current directory and all sub-directories?

Comment: Ok, this is really rather outside the purview of SO, but before I flag this post I'll just suggest you look at the `-c` flag on grep. Specifically, I would do `find . -name 'FileName' -exec grep -c '@' '{}' \+` or something like that.

Comment: This works... Thanks a lot :)